# showing checkbox on itemswipe in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm creating a Sencha Touch application and want to code a swipe functionality on my list items.

It should work like this:
1. When user swipes the list item to the right the list item should follow. 
2. "Under" the list item there should be a checkbox that the user can check/uncheck.

My listener so far is:

```
itemswipe: function (list, idx, target, record, evt) {
    alert(record.data.name);
}
```

This works fine but I need some help on the points above. How do I slide the actual list item to the right and show the checkbox?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Please check out the [clear app](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/clear/) to see the animation I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea, but since you have access to the list and index, you can easily add a class to the node, then use CSS to style it:

```
list.getItemAt(idx).addCls('swiped');
```

Then in your app.css have something like:

```
.swiped .x-innerhtml { margin-left: 30px; }
.itemContent { z-index: 20; /* above checkbox below */ }
.theCheckbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /* other styles to position the checkbox "under" the list item */
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Just an idea... let me know if that works for you.

Comment: hmmm...that could work! Question is how I would place a checkbox under the tpl. Any ideas there?

Comment: Well, well, you could use `position:relative;left:-30px;` on the checkbox, then shift the `left` property to 0 when it has the `.swiped` class.

Comment: Worked fine! This is absolutely one way of doing it. Only problem is that is is not really dragging the list item :) But for me this solution works :)

Comment: Hmm... yeah, I can see that. Maybe you need to add a `div` around both elements with the list item content and checkbox next to each other, positioned off screen to the left by `30px` or so. Then instead of changing the class, animate the containing `div` on swipe.